# Directional spread of a raster from a point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I've created a cost distance raster from a set of points and a cost raster using arcgis pro.

[image: Cost raster]

I want to know whats the main direction of all the cost cells. I tried to use a watershed, but i'm not sure if thats the right heading. What method would be most usefull?

**Update**
I tried the euclidean direction, but I cant seem to get it right, as there is NaN cells around the cells. 
[image: Euclidean direction]

Comment: Have a look at the Euclidean Direction (Spatial Analyst)  tool.

Comment: @Hornbydd Thansk for the suggestion. I'm not really sure if I did it correctly, as it turned out to take the NaN cells a find the heading there. The problem is so that around all the shapes there are NaN cells. Would I have to make every "shape" to a single raster to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

What if you tried the Cost Allocation tool instead of Euclidean Direction. Then, on the resulting zones, run Zonal Geometry to define the Centroid of each allocation zone. From there, you could have the x,y of your origin and the x,y of your centroid and could compute the bearing. You could even take it one step further and create Cost path lines from source to centroid, using a constant value Raster (to get straight lines) and that would essentially show magnitude as well.

If you are limiting your cost distance as shown in your images, you could forgo the cost allocation and just convert those areas to unique zones (use Region Group), then get the centroid of those zones.